# Spring Boot Test- How to avoid spawning srver

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-boot

**Requirement** I have a spring boot application and respective unit and integration tests.
Since my tests are relying setup part which is time consuming, i need to do-

1. Invoke selective tests
2. Tests should be invoked within pre-configured test server

**What i tried** I got to know about surefire plugin where i configured like below configuration-

```
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <forkCount>0</forkCount>
            <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
        </configuration>
```

But still i see test server gets started to execute the testes. Difference is, because of above configuration it uses same PID (used `mvn test`). So my ask is is there any way to run spring boot test cases without starting the test server and should use pre-configured test server.

Comment: If you run a Spring boot application to execute your unit tests, then you're probably doing something wrong. Also, if you want to use a preconfigured test server, you require a completely different setup, because I don't think you will be able to get access to the application context if you're running your tests on another server. In that case you'll have to look more into E2E testing. For example, by invoking a REST API (RestAssured) or by calling your web application (Selenium) and verifying what ends up into the database and as a result in your REST API or your web application.